# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'render')

Tags: javascript, three.js

I was practicing to make some animations with ThreeJS but it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'render')".
I have no clue about this error. This is my first time using ThreeJS, so I don't know much about it.

```
<body>
<script src="main.js" type="module" defer></script>

<script type="module">
    import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.124.0/build/three.module.js';
    let scene, camera, renderer, starGeo, stars;

    function init() {
      //create scene object
      const scene = new THREE.Scene();
      
      //setup camera with facing upward
      const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60,window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
      camera.position.z = 1;
      camera.rotation.x = Math.PI/2;
      
      //setup renderer
      const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        starGeo = new THREE.Geometry();
            for(let i=0;i<6000;i++) {
                let star = new THREE.Vector3(
                Math.random() * 600 - 300,
                Math.random() * 600 - 300,
                Math.random() * 600 - 300
            );
            star.velocity = 0;
            star.acceleration = 0.02;
            starGeo.vertices.push(star);
            }
            let sprite = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'star.png' );
            let starMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
                color: 0xaaaaaa,
                size: 0.7,
                map: sprite
            });

            stars = new THREE.Points(starGeo,starMaterial);
            scene.add(stars);

      animate(); 
    }
    //rendering loop
    function animate() {
        starGeo.vertices.forEach(p => {
            p.velocity += p.acceleration
            p.y -= p.velocity;
            
            if (p.y < -200) {
            p.y = 200;
            p.velocity = 0;
            }
        });
    starGeo.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
    stars.rotation.y +=0.002;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
    init();
 </script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You declare `let render;` and then never assign a value to it. Please see [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](/q/500431/4642212).

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this line:
`const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();`
To be:
`renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();`

The problem was that you never assigned a value to the `let renderer` at the higher scope and had another constant with the same name at the `init()` function scope which is not available in `animate()` function scope.